# Deciding whether there exists a certain function based on connectedness

Tags: real-analysis, functions, metric-spaces, connectedness

**Problem:**

Let $$A=\left\{(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^{2}:(x-1)^{2}+y^{2}=1\right\} \cup\left\{(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^{2}:(x+1)^{2}+y^{2}=1\right\}$$ and $$B=\left\{(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^{2}: x^{2}+y^{2}=1\right\}$$

Decide whether there exists a continuous and surjective function
$$
f: A \longrightarrow B
$$

**Attempt:**

I have been trying to solve the above problem as follows:

**1.** Note that $B$ is connected, since it is just the unit circle in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$

**2.** Note that $A$ is also connected. Why is that? Well, $A$ is the union of two connected sets with non-empty intersection and is therefore connected.

Furthermore, regarding connected sets, it holds that a metric space $\left(M, d\right)$ is **disconnected** if, and only if, there exists a **continuous and surjective function**
$$
f: M \rightarrow\{0,1\}
$$

**However**, since both $A$ and $B$ are connected sets, I can't really use the above proposition to reach a contradiction of some sort, which was my initial strategy.

More specifically, I was hoping to exhibit a continuous surjection between a connected set and $\{0,1\}$, therefore reaching a contradiction. I would do this by using the fact that the composition of surjective funcions is still surjective or something similar.

Is there a way to solve the problem using my initial thoughts? If not, what else should I consider to approach the above problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you considered that maybe $f$ does exist?

Comment: An $f$ certainly does exist, and I think if you shift your thinking away from disproving it by connectedness, you'll find one without too much hassle (hint: try mapping each disc in $A$ surjectively onto $B$).

Comment: That is interesting. Initially i thought this could be the case, but got nothing out of it, so I figured it should be the other way around

Comment: Do you have any tips on how to construct such a continuous surjection? Maybe think about projections?

Comment: It came to my mind the ideia of constructing a function that moves the circumference to the origin by a translation in the x axis. Does that make sense?

Comment: @Lucas Your last comment has made me think that perhaps your question is backwards? Are you, instead, trying to find a surjective map of $B$ onto $A$? This should still be doable, but is less straightforward.

Comment: Interesting! However the question is stated correctly, just checked it

Comment: I'm not sure I can give much more detailed hints than I already did, but let's give it a try. Think about a simple map that maps the circle $\{(x, y) \in \Bbb{R}^2 : (x - 1)^2 + y^2 = 1\}$ onto $B$. Now, think of a simple map that maps the circle $\{ (x, y) \in \Bbb{R}^2: (x + 1)^2 + y^2 = 1\}$ onto $B$. Think about this: where does the point $(0, 0)$ map to in each case? If you can use rotations or reflections to make $(0, 0)$ map to the same point in each case, then combining the two maps on the domain $A$ will form a continuous surjection onto $B$. There are no more hints I can think of!

Comment: Hmmmmm, I think I got it! Where can I write my solution afterwards so someone can check it?

Comment: You can write it as an answer to your own question! If you don't feel confident enough in it, check the "community wiki" box. This means that you won't gain reputation from your answer, but you won't lose reputation for it either. Also, since nobody has answered (or even voted) on your question, you could also just edit in your solution into your question, and tag it [tag:solution-verification]. Or, finally, you could delete this question and ask a new one, but that's a grey area with respect to the site rules. It's better just to edit, I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function $f(x,y) = (|x|-1,y)$ is continuous and maps $A$ onto $B$.

The absolute value function “folds” negative numbers onto positive numbers, so applied in the $x$-coordinate will fold the circle in the left half of the plane onto the circle in the right half.  Then subtracting one will move this doubled circle back to place its center at the origin.

Comment: Interesting. Quick question: Do you think there exists a mapping from $B$ to $A$ which is onto? My initial guess is that it is not possible, as one would have to map $\left(0,0\right)$ to both $\left(1, 0\right)$ and $\left(-1,0\right)$

Comment: Is there a way to get around that and still preserve continuity and surjectivity?

Comment: Well, $(0,0)$ is not in $B$, so you don't have to worry about that.  But to your question: draw two circles inside $B$, of radius $1/2$, centered at $(1/2,0)$ and $(-1/2,0)$.  Call that space $A'$.  There is a continuous map from $B$ to $A'$, which takes each point $(x,y)$ in $B$ to a point $(x,y')$ in $A'$, in the same quadrant as $(x,y)$.  Then dilate by a factor of $2$ to map $A'$ onto $A$.

Comment: Very very interesting! But that function will not be continuous, right? By the way, you end up figuring the mappings through geometric interpretation, right?

Comment: If we're going to keep going down this road you should probably ask a new question `:-)`